# json.parse doesn't like google maps suggest

Tags: javascript, json

Would like to use the return of: http://maps.google.de/maps/suggest?q=ham&cp=1&hl=de&gl=de&v=2&json=b as a JSON object in a firefox extension. I tried to parse it using JSON.parse and it didn't work.

Is there another way instead of using regex to use it as a JSON object?

```
var xhr_return = JSON.parse(rtoparse);
```

> returns: SyntaxError: JSON.parse

other json files in my script work without problems.

Comment: "It didn't work" is **never** an acceptable reason for abandoning a solution. Why didn't it work?

Comment: @phihag, sure it is. If you have another solution.

Comment: @eyelidlessness No, because "it didn't work" is so underspecified that it does not even have to be related to the solution: It can include causes such as power, service, or network outages.

Comment: @phihag, if we want to get pedantic, none of those are cases of **it** didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you're using is not part of google's [official maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) and therefore subject to change, blockage, etc. . You should really use the official API. That being said, despite the URL containing `json`, the result is YAML, not JSON. Set the JSON parameter to `a` (instead of `b`) to get a JSON result.

Comment: thx phihag - do you have any clue which url concrete i could use from the google maps api?

Answer (score 2):

It is not JSON. Unlike in a JavaScript object literal, a JSON-key must be surrounded with double quotes.

**An example:**

The data from your link looks like this:

```
{suggestion:[{query:"Hamburg" ...
```

But it must look like this in order to be valid JSON:

```
{"suggestion":[{"query":"Hamburg" ...
```

Comment: Not a clue. +1'd to get you level again :P.

Comment: Thank you Matt (and some other anonymous person) :)

Answer (score 1):

Json from [url](http://maps.google.de/maps/suggest?q=ham&cp=1&hl=de&gl=de&v=2&json=b) you provided is not valid, you can check it [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/). So, because of json is not valid, `JSON.parse` throw exception.

Fix the json format and parse it with `JSON.parse`.